# How can I enable Personal Hotspot on iOS 7 even though my carrier has disabled it?

Tags: ios, tethering

On my iPhone running iOS 7, I have the Personal Hotspot feature, but I can't turn it on. I've read that it's been disabled by my carrier, AT&T, since the feature is plan dependent. How can I bypass this and still enable Personal Hotspot?

Comment: Im not sure what is subjective. The fact is that on the same carrier and same plan i can use hotspot on my android with no problem. How could there be a device specific restriction for the iphone? I travel a lot. What if i go to a country and use a carrier thats not even on apples list? And this is also a fact because the carrier i use in my home country is not listed on apples carrier list. My question is why can my android bypass this restriction and not the iphone?

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to jailbreak, you can use [**TetherMe**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/net.tetherme.tetherme). It will enable Personal Hotspot then change the location of the data to appear to be coming from inside the device, thereby bypassing the carrier's disable.

> ## [image: TetherMe] [TetherMe](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/net.tetherme.tetherme)
>
> Dynamically enables native tethering or personal hotspot for iOS3.X or newer devices. This should work on any carrier without the need for customised bundles or preferences.
>
> TetherMe has been tested to work on all iOS versions from 3.0 to 6.1 and works by telling the iPhone to allow tethering on any APN that is used for iPhone data. As a result, you should not be charged any more for tethering data than normal data by your phone company as all tethering data appears to come from the phone itself.